# List of dictionaries that should be filtered by certain values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts and would like to have only unique values based on certain keys.

Lets say I have

```
data = [{name: "John", age: "20", occupation: "Python pro"}, \
        {name: "Jack", age: "80", occupation: "Olympic Athlete"}, \
        {name: "John", age: "20", occupation: "Student"}]
```

I would like to reduce it based on keys 'name' and 'age' to have it look like

```
[{name: "John", age: "20", occupation: "Python pro"}, \
 {name: "Jack", age: "80", occupation: "Olympic Athlete"}]
```

I have tried the following but didn't realize the glaring problem where it would basically add everything every time.

```
    all_drives =  drivesInBuilder("object") + drivesInBuilder("account") + drivesInBuilder("container")
    reduced_list = [(x["ip address"], x["name"]) for x in all_drives]
    unique_list = list(set(reduced_list))
    unique_drives = [x for x in all_drives if (x["ip address"], x["name"]) in unique_list]
    print(unique_drives)
```

Comment: Why is your first example completely unrelated to your second example? It is very hard to tell what your actual problem/question is. Do you not understand why your code is not filtering properly? Or do you want to change it to filter based on some criteria? Please edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Wilduck The first example is a simplified version of my actual problem. The 2nd part is just an example of what I tried in my actual problem... mostly because people ask "what have you tried?".

Comment: sure, obviously. But you didn't explain how they relate to each other or *most importantly* what your question is.

Comment: Sorry for confusing things, @Wilduck. I'll be more concise next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = [{"name": "John", "age": "20", "occupation": "Python pro"}, \
        {"name": "Jack", "age": "80", "occupation": "Olympic Athlete"}, \
        {"name": "John", "age": "20", "occupation": "Student"}]

new_data = []
names_ages = set([])
for d in data:
    name_age = (d["name"], d["age"])
    if name_age not in names_ages:
        new_data.append(d)
    names_ages.add(name_age)

print new_data
# [{'age': '20', 'name': 'John', 'occupation': 'Python pro'},
#  {'age': '80', 'name': 'Jack', 'occupation': 'Olympic Athlete'}]
```

Comment: beat me, posted the same :) +1

Comment: Beat me as well. Another option would be to delete the entry rather than create auxiliary list.